# Use jquery to alter link attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm trying to make a page that generates a quote when you click a 'quote' button and then you can tweet the quote using the twitter button. [Here](https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet) is a link to the twitter button.

The twitter button allows you to tweet out specific text that you want by altering the 'data-text' attribute.

I would like to use my 'quote' button to generate a quote and at the same time alter the data-text attribute of my twitter button so I can click the twitter button after and tweet out a specific quote.

So far I have this which is part of my click function:

```
$("a").prop("data-text", quotes[j]);
```

Where j is an index of the quote array but I can't seem to get it to work.

EDIT: Here is a working demo: http://codepen.io/michaelaharvey/pen/wMzGJR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

``` '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js`` loads an ```iframe`into`.asdf`, removing exisiting`a`element within`.asdf`. When attempting to access`a`element within`iframe`

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' 
property from 'HTMLIFrameElement':
Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at   
"http://stacksnippets.net" from accessing a frame at 
"http://platform.twitter.com".  
Both frames are sandboxed and lack the "allow-same-origin" flag.
```

logged to `console`

Comment: couldnt get it to work i cant figure out why :( http://codepen.io/michaelaharvey/pen/wMzGJR

Answer (score 2):

Im going to be different and suggest using the jquery data method https://api.jquery.com/data/

```
$("a").data("text", quotes[j]);
```

Comment: no luck with the data method. im not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: can you please post your partial html and this quotes array variable? That may help us track down your issue

Comment: maybe you can check out my demo? thanks!!! http://codepen.io/michaelaharvey/pen/wMzGJR

Comment: Can you provide the documentation where it says to add the data-text ? It looks like the html you add from twitter changes your anchor into their custom iframe?

Comment: if you change the data-text attribute it changes what gets tweeted out. maybe there is another way to do it?

Comment: if your question is to just get data-text on an anchor, any of our answers work. I think your real question is how to get the twitter button working right? This is the documentation I found https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button . Here it says you set the text for the tweet in the query string parameter of your anchor. There are data attributes but for things like size. If you have documentation that says to use data-text, can you share it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98949/discussion-between-alexbezek-and-michael-harvey).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `.attr`

```
$("a").attr("data-text", quotes[j]);
```

Comment: Assuming `quotes[j]` is valid, it should work. Check out this example https://jsfiddle.net/pjuouo9s/1/

Comment: maybe you can check out my demo and see what im doing wrong?  http://codepen.io/michaelaharvey/pen/wMzGJR

Answer (score 1):

If you check DOM you will not find any `a` tag, but `.data,.attr,.prop`will require the element to be present in DOM

[FROM THIS LINK](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.